# Display html formated text in report

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, reportserver

In my report I display a record from a table of my database. One of my columns has data formated as html. I want to display this as rendered html.

So

```
<b>nice header</b>
```

should render 
**nice header**

Can I do this in a report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Right-click on your text
2. Goto Placeholder properties
3. Set the markup type to HTML

From [Here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/greg_low/archive/2008/08/25/displaying-html-content-in-reporting-services-2008.aspx) and [Here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/greg_low/archive/2008/12/19/rendering-html-in-reporting-services-text-boxes-in-sql-server-2008.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. I had a hard time to realy click on the text and not on the data container. What a UI...

Answer (score 0):

one way would be in your case would be to do formatting based on expressions or using .NET code in your report, and saying if you see some html tag to do formatting like "x"